# DWG to Blender, how can I import

Tags: import

I use software to produce kitchen visuals that use dwg files, does anyone know how I can get this file into Blender, is there a free converter or any other way so I can try to use Blender to render?

I look forward to any feedback

Answer (score 1):

### Convert them in DXF

DWG is a cad standard format, but it's propetary so it's unlikely that you'll find a direct importer soon. I would save those file from the cad application in the DXF format and then import those.

Blender has a built in DXF importer that works quite well. You just have to enable it from the user preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply Carlo, do you have any recommendations of what I can use to convert the DWG to DXF